# Why does the Parcelable.Creator field decrease Jackson performance dramatically?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I read in JSON data from a file and convert the contents to my model objects. I noticed lately that performance was going down and after debugging Ive found that the `Parcelable.Creator` field was the cause.

**Simply removing the Parcelable.Creator field resulted in a 100-200% speed increase when converting the String to my model classes.**

**Why is that?**

Here are my timings, first one being the Fw class **with** the `Parcelable.Creator` field, and `FwNoParcel` being an exactly identical class **without** any `Parcelable.Creator` field.

```
D/BaseActivity$Player﹕ Stats for ReadFw; Took 3086 ms.
D/BaseActivity$Player﹕ Stats for ReadFwNoParcel; Took 1281 ms.
```

**And here is the model object Im playing with.**

```
public static final class Fw implements Parcelable{
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String comment;
    public String programId;
    public int programDayIndex = -1;
    public long startTime;
    public long endTime;
    public ArrayList<FitnessActivity> activities;

    public Fw() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public Fw(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
        comment = in.readString();
        programId = in.readString();
        programDayIndex = in.readInt();
        startTime = in.readLong();
        endTime = in.readLong();
        in.readList(activities, FitnessActivity.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(comment);
        dest.writeString(programId);
        dest.writeInt(programDayIndex);
        dest.writeLong(startTime);
        dest.writeLong(endTime);
        dest.writeList(activities);
    }

    public static final Creator<Fw> CREATOR = new Creator<Fw>() {
        @Override
        public Fw createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Fw(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Fw[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Fw[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**And lastly heres the code I am using to actually read the file and convert it to my model objects. (Simplified for readability).**

```
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = ...

//getFw
//getFwNoParcel is exactly identical.
final File file = ... //A file containing tons of data in JSON format.
final CollectionType type 
    = MAPPER.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Fw.class);
return MAPPER.reader(type).readValue(file);
```

Comment: Use Traceview and determine exactly where your time is being spent.

Comment: @CommonsWare The only difference is that String.charAt and String.equals are both called more with the Parcelable.Creator field (28k vs 2k calls).